# Rel. Prime algebra/elementary number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Hello I have two questions 
1)   show that $5n+2$ and $12n+5$ are relatively prime. 
Can I do it this way?

From Euclids algortihm.

$12n+5=(5n+2) \cdot 2 +(2n+1)$

$5n+2=(2n+1) \cdot 2 +n$

$2n+1=(n) \cdot 2 +1$

$n=1 \cdot n + 0$

Hence gcd=1

My second question is 
let a,b,c $\in$ Z
suppose $c|a+b$ and $(a,b)=1$ show that c is relatively prime to both a and b.
Now sure how to start I know that I can write $au+bv=1$ and $a+b=ct$ but i dont know if that is useful

Answer (score 1):

For 1. it is OK what you do.

For the second part. Suppose $c$ and $a$ are not relatively prime. Then there exist prime $p$ such that $p|a$ and $p|c$, so $a= dp$ and $p|dp+b$ so:

$$p|(dp+b)-dp =b$$

$p|b$ and this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$5(12n+5)-12(5n+2)=1$$
Then according to Bezout lemma they are coprime.

Comment: Bezout says the converse: if $(12n+5)$ and $(5n+2)$ are coprime then there are $r,s$ with $r(12n+5)+s(5n+2)=1$. But of course, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925807/if-ar-bs-1-then-gcda-s-gcdr-b-gcdr-s-1) explains that $ra+sb=1$ also implies that $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately we didn't learn about bezout's lemma yet

Comment: @Djhoe You don't need Bezout's Lemma. From $ra+sb=1$ it follows directly that $gcd(a,b)=1$,see the duplicate above.

Comment: Yes you're right!