# Prove that ∀a, b, u, v ∈ Z − {0} ua + vb = 1 → gcd(a, b) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How can I prove this statement:

$\forall a,b,u,v \in \mathbb{Z} - \big\{{0\big\}}\hspace{0.7em}ua+vb=1 \rightarrow \gcd(a,b)=1$

I don't even really know how to start off.

Probably with Euclid's Extended GCD Algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, because the the proof of the *Extended  Euclidean algorithm* relies on this fact.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671748/show-that-if-ar-bs-1-for-some-r-and-s-then-a-and-b-are-relatively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that states that the gcd of two numbers is the minimal (natural) linear combination of them. I.e.,
$$\gcd\left(m,n\right)=\min\left\{am+bn\in\mathbb{N}\middle|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

Another way is to prove it by definition: show that if $d|a$ and $d|b$, then $d=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is a divisor of $ua+vb$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(a,b)\mid ua$ and $\gcd(a,b)\mid vb$, we get $\gcd(a,b)\mid ua+vb=1$.